# All js.erb runs but not executing in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am working a rails 4 project and I have been using the rails Ajax method transporting data from controller to js.erb and this has been working fine. I notice for a while that all the js.erb javascript has stoped working but looking at the file from the server the request are sent as `js` and it renders correctly.

One of the responses:

```
Started GET "/comments/new?comment%5Bcommentable_id%5D=26&comment%5Bcommentable_type%5D=Question" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-21 13:11:32 +0100
Processing by CommentsController#new as JS
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"commentable_id"=>"26", "commentable_type"=>"Question"}}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 20 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_requested_at" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 20  [["last_requested_at", Sun, 21 Aug 2016 12:11:32 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sun, 21 Aug 2016 12:11:32 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  User Load (1.0ms)  Select users.* from users, user_categories where user_categories.user_id = users.id and user_categories.category_id in (select user_categories.category_id from user_categories where user_categories.user_id = 20) and users.id not in (20) and users.id not in (SELECT users.id FROM users INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.followed_id and relationships.follower_id = 20) group by users.id limit 5
  Rendered comments/_form.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered comments/new.js.erb (2.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 3.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

This happends in all the application js.erb file but all the script(vanilar, coffee, and jquery) from assets files works find. I've been debuging for months now and I couldn't fine what is wrong.

when I tried inspecting form chrome I get 200 response as js but then no execution, I've also tried diffrent browsers.

[image: browser xhr inspector]

here is the new comments new.js.erb

```
<% if @comment.commentable_type == "Question" %>
    $('#comment-form').append('<%= escape_javascript render("form") %>');
    $('.comment_link').hide();
 <% else %>
    $('#comment-form_<%= @comment.commentable_id %>').append('<%= escape_javascript render("form") %>');
    $('.comment_link').hide();
<% end %>

$('.cancel-comment').click(function() {
  $('#new_comment, .comment-form').hide();
  $('.comment_link').show();
})
```

here is the link that call's fires the Ajax requestion:

```
<%= link_to " Add a comment", new_comment_path(:comment => { :commentable_type => @question.class.name,
                         :commentable_id => @question.id}),
                         :remote => true,
                         :class => "comment_link",
                         id:"comment_link"  %>
```

Controller method:

```
def new
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render layout: false }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Previously working? Did u add extension to your view file .js.. What is the file content when open as standalone?

Comment: did you select proper  `DOM` element for appending data?

Comment: @JamesTan yeah, they were all working properly. this is now happing in all other .js.erb file not even js alert works there.

uzaif yes, I am selecting the Dom very well beside all kind of javascript methods are not executing.

Comment: u have remote: true in link_to, is that intentional?

Comment: yes, it's intentional @JamesTan

Comment: @OnozorObogbareAlex is your problem solved or still have some issue?

Comment: @VKatz it still has issues, and am still trying to debug.

Answer (score 3):

remove from action. after remove respond_to block you can access in js.erb file.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render layout: false }
end
```

Comment: Kindly Elaborate I don't get you.

Comment: do you want to do something in js.erb file? if so then you have to remove respond block?